# Problem in defining the initial conditions for asymtotic expansion (Heat Equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, heat-equation, perturbation-theory

I have been trying to find the asymptotic (innner/outer) expansion of the follwing Heat Equation (with Dirichlet boundary condition):
$$\begin{cases}
      u_t-\epsilon.u_{xx}=0 & x<0,\; t\in \mathbb{R^{+*}} \\
      u(t,0)=0 & t\in \mathbb{R^{+*}} \\
u(0,x)=e^{-\frac{-x}{2\epsilon}}        & x<0 
\end{cases}$$
So the only boundary layer, is in the boudary condition at $\{x=0\}$.

My problem is that when I define the asymptotic outer expansion:
$$u=u^0+\epsilon u^1+...$$
I can't find the initial conditions for $u^k$ for all $k\geq 0$. Because I can't write $e^{\frac{-x}{\epsilon}}$ as $\sum_{k\geq0}g^k(x)\epsilon^k$.

So that I can say for example: $u^0(0,x)=g^0(x)$

Comment: Away from 0, you can just set $g^k(x)=0$, and near zero I think you can do a boundary-layer rescaling $\eta=x/\epsilon$.

Comment: @David, should we introduce also the rescaling $y=t/\epsilon$ ? and also you suggest a rescaling near the boudary layer, but what intial condition should I consider ?

Comment: Inside the boundary layer you can use $u(\eta) = e^\eta$ I think. I'm not sure about the time scale without writing it out, but I think $t/\epsilon$ might be the correct thing to do.

Comment: @BrianTag have you got result on this issue?